# Using bash to run remote script on Linux board

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

I can execute following command on my Windows 10 machine using OpenSSH with no problem:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.145 cd /home/root/proj;./a.sh arg1
```

This command will run the remote Linux script `a.sh` with parameter `arg1` passed to it.

Now I'm trying to create a bash script on my Windows machine that will do this automatically.

My bash script file `test.sh` contains the following command:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.145 'cd /home/root/proj;./a.sh arg1'
```

However, when I enter `bash test.sh` from my DOS command window, it fails running the remote script `a.sh`. I'm using Git for Windows on my Windows machine.

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well this seems to work ok:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.145 <<DONE
cd /home/root/proj
./a.sh arg1
```